# How I can get ID from controller in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I post this data from submit button:
`pesanans"=>{"14"=>{"id"=>"0", "harga"=>"18500", "jumlah"=>"6"}, "15"=>{"id"=>"0", "harga"=>"18000", "jumlah"=>"9"}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}"`

How I can get id value from controller?

I've tried: 
`@pesanan = Pesanan.find_by_id(params[:pesanans][:id])`
But not get result anything

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Id is 14 or 15? What 's your expect?

Comment: my expect id is 14 and 15

Comment: I also want to get params(:jumlah)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [strong params](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Create a new method in your controller like this:

```
def pesanans_params
  params.require(:pesanans).permit(:harga, :jumlah)
end
```

Now you can do:

```
@pesanan.update_attributes(pesanans_params)
```

And it will create a 'whitelist' of allowed fields

You can also access fields directly through it like `pesanans_params[:harga]`

Answer (score 0):

The value of `params[:pesanas]` is a hash, you have two posible `:id` in your example. If you know they are all the same you can do `params[:pesanas].values.first[:id]` but it's not really clear on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two `ids` in one request, if you need a both then just use `.where` query.

But this will focus always on first object no matter how many passing.

`@pesanan = Pesanan.find_by(id: params[:pesanans].keys.first.to_i)`

**Sample:**

```
#>irb

x = {"14"=>{"id"=>"0", "harga"=>"18500", "jumlah"=>"6"}, "15"=>{"id"=>"0", "harga"=>"18000", "jumlah"=>"9"}}

x.keys
=> ["14", "15"]

x.values
=> [{"id"=>"0", "harga"=>"18500", "jumlah"=>"6"}, {"id"=>"0", "harga"=>"18000", "jumlah"=>"9"}]
```